# Kafka Consumer with Circuit Breaker, Retry Patterns using Resilience4j

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, resilience4j

I need some help in understanding how I can come up with a solution using Spring boot, Kafka, Resilence4J to achieve a microservice call from my Kafka Consumer. Let's say if the Microservice is down then I need to notify my Kafka consumer using a circuit breaker pattern to stop fetching the messages/events until the Microservice is up and running.

Comment: Hi, just to clarify.
You have a service A which is consuming messages from a topic and calls another service B for every new message? You want to stop consuming messages from the topic if service B is down?

Comment: @RobertWinkler absolutely right. And also try to do a retry before opening the circuit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Spring Kafka, you could use the `pause` and `resume` methods depending on the CircuitBreaker state transitions. The best way I found for this is to define it as "supervisor" with an @Configuration Annotation. Resilience4j is also used.

```
@Configuration
public class CircuitBreakerConsumerConfiguration {

public CircuitBreakerConsumerConfiguration(CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry, KafkaManager kafkaManager) {
    circuitBreakerRegistry.circuitBreaker("yourCBName").getEventPublisher().onStateTransition(event -> {
  
        switch (event.getStateTransition()) {
            case CLOSED_TO_OPEN:
            case CLOSED_TO_FORCED_OPEN:
            case HALF_OPEN_TO_OPEN:
                kafkaManager.pause();
                break;
            case OPEN_TO_HALF_OPEN:
            case HALF_OPEN_TO_CLOSED:
            case FORCED_OPEN_TO_CLOSED:
            case FORCED_OPEN_TO_HALF_OPEN:
                kafkaManager.resume();
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown transition state: " + event.getStateTransition());
        }
    });
   }
}
```

This is what I used in combination with a KafkaManager annotated with `@Component`.

```
@Component
public class KafkaManager {
  private final KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

  public KafkaManager(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
    this.registry = registry;
  }
  public void pause() {   
    registry.getListenerContainers().forEach(MessageListenerContainer::pause);
  }

  public void resume() {
    registry.getListenerContainers().forEach(MessageListenerContainer::resume);
  }
}
```

In addition my consumer service looks like this:

```
  @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${topic.name}'}", concurrency = "1", id = "CBListener")
public void receive(final ConsumerRecord<String, ReplayData> replayData, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) throws
        Exception {

    try {
        httpClientServiceCB.receiveHandleCircuitBreaker(replayData);
        acknowledgement.acknowledge();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        acknowledgment.nack(1000);
    }
}
```

And the `@CircuitBreaker` Annotation:

```
@CircuitBreaker(name = "yourCBName")
public void receiveHandleCircuitBreaker(ConsumerRecord<String, ReplayData> replayData) throws
        Exception {
    try {
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/item", String.class);
    } catch (Exception e                                                                       ) {
       
        // throwing the exception is needed to trigger the Circuit Breaker state change
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

And this is additionally supplemented by the following `application.properties`

```
  resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.yourCBName.failure-rate-threshold=80
  resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.yourCBName.sliding-window-type=COUNT_BASED
  resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.yourCBName.sliding-window-size=5
  resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.yourCBName.wait-duration-in-open-state=10000
  resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.yourCBName.automatic-transition-from-open-to-half-open-enabled=true
  spring.kafka.consumer.enable.auto.commit = false
  spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode = MANUAL_IMMEDIATE
```

Also have a look at https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker

Comment: Is this compatible with the SeekToCurrentErrorHandler / DefaultErrorHandler implementation used to retry?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Kafka, you could maybe use the `pause` and `resume` methods of the `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` class.
You can attach an EventListener to the CircuitBreaker which listens on state transitions and pauses or resumes processing of events. Inject the CircuitBreakerRegistry into you bean:

```
circuitBreakerRegistry.circuitBreaker("yourCBName").getEventPublisher().onStateTransition(
                        event -> {
                            switch (event.getStateTransition()) {
                                case CLOSED_TO_OPEN:
                                    container.pause();
                                case OPEN_TO_HALF_OPEN:
                                    container.resume();
                                case HALF_OPEN_TO_CLOSED:
                                    container.resume();
                                case HALF_OPEN_TO_OPEN:
                                    container.pause();
                                case CLOSED_TO_FORCED_OPEN:
                                    container.pause();
                                case FORCED_OPEN_TO_CLOSED:
                                    container.resume();
                                case FORCED_OPEN_TO_HALF_OPEN:
                                    container.resume();
                                default:
                            }
                        }
                );
```